# Websockets that change ports? How do I catch them all :) 8050, 8053, 8073..etc

Tags: python, json, networking, websocket

There is this website (blitzortung[.]org) that gathers **live lightning data**, and I would really like to learn more about catching live data by writing a script that connects to the website and saves the websockets as they arrive, all the data (stock prices are also commonly 'caught' and there are a lot of tutorials, but the 'problem' doesn't occur there as far as I know or don't know), and when I do the inspect element thingy using Chrome and go to Network, and then click on `ws` (websockets), I've noticed that the ports change from time to time. I've noticed `8050` to `8090` and sometimes it takes a few seconds, sometimes a couple of minutes, or even 45? Do they really change because the `80xx` stays?

So, how should I approach this? I'm using Python 3 and `websocket-client`  fyi

Lightning strike data is in JSON format, this is all I want, as close to real-time as it gets:

```
{time: 1527498164439381800, lat: 39.285885, lon: 40.87246, alt: 0, pol: 0, mds: 5004, mcg: 244,…}
```

Edit:  `ws.send(request)`  where request is the map key you can find inspecting the website, and as stated in the comments, any port from `8050` to `8090` works for `ws.connect()`.

Comment: have you tried `websocket-client` ? https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/

Comment: Ports don't matter. See js source code on website: `var rnd= parseInt (Math.random()*40)+50;`, it is just a random number between `8050` and `8090`. You can use any of them in your python code.

Comment: Wow that really helps!